# when i empty my input, this reset the items state of my container. What to do to fix this

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I would like my app to make a comparison between two items selected in my container,
when I search a second items Global state 'comparaison' and
local state gonna reinitialized. How to fix it

context component:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react'


export const UpperState = createContext()

    const GlobalState = (props) =>{ 
    const [pokemons,setPokemons] = useState([])
    const [comparaison,setComparaison] = useState({0: null,1: null})
    const val = {
        pokemons,
        comparaison,
        setPokemons,
        setComparaison

    }

    return(
        <UpperState.Provider value={val}>
            {console.log('render')}
            {props.children}
        </UpperState.Provider>
     )
}

export default GlobalState
```

searchBar component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'


import PokeContainer from './PokeContainer'

export default function SearchBar() {
    const [filterText,setFilterText] = useState('')

    function handleChange(e) {
        setFilterText(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <div className='SearchBar'>
            <input type="text" name="" id="SearchInput" placeholder='Pokemons...' onChange={handleChange} value={filterText} />
            <PokeContainer filterText={filterText}  />
        </div>

    )
}
```

items container component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'


import PokeContainer from './PokeContainer'

export default function SearchBar() {
    const [filterText,setFilterText] = useState('')

    function handleChange(e) {
        setFilterText(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <div className='SearchBar'>
            <input type="text" name="" id="SearchInput" placeholder='Pokemons...' onChange={handleChange} value={filterText} />
            <PokeContainer filterText={filterText}  />
        </div>

    )
}
```

items Components:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { UpperState } from '../../../contextApi/GlobalState'

export default function PokeRow({data,counter}) {
    const val = useContext(UpperState)
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(show){
            if(val.comparaison[0] === null){
                val.setComparaison(s=>({
                    ...s,
                    0:data.id
                }))  
            } else {
                val.setComparaison(s=>({
                    ...s,
                    1:data.id
                }))
            }
        } else {
            for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(val.comparaison)){
                if(value !== null && value.id === data.id){
                    val.setComparaison(s=>({
                        ...s,
                        [`${key}`]:null
                    }))
                }
            }
        }
    },[show])

    function handleClick(e){
        const targetId = e.target.id
        setShow(!show)
    
        if(counter>= 2 && !show){
            console.log('2 composant max');
            return 
        }  
    }

    return (
        <li id={data.id} onClick={ handleClick } >
            {data.langName}: {JSON.stringify(show)}
        </li>
    )
}
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-agnesi-05wdt?file=/.gitignore

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Having a CodeSandbox example is great, but please also post the relevant bits of your code in the question.

Comment: Is it better like this?